.NET8 & Serilog: partially renders string templates of the HTTP request logger
I am having a problem with Serilog logging and i don't knwo where to start to look for it.
Our application logs partially as you can see from a single entry of our logs:
{"@t":"2024-10-25T09:14:41.0795640Z","@mt":"Request finished {Protocol} {Method} {Scheme}://{Host}{PathBase}{Path}{QueryString} - {StatusCode} {ContentLength} {ContentType} {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms","ElapsedMilliseconds":200.9298,"StatusCode":200,"ContentType":null,"ContentLength":null,"Protocol":"HTTP/1.1","Method":"GET","Scheme":"http","Host":"10.3.2.5:8080","PathBase":"","Path":"/api/health/liveness","QueryString":"","EventId":{"Id":2},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics","RequestId":"0HN7JB81LU0N3:00000001","RequestPath":"/api/health/liveness","ConnectionId":"0HN7JB81LU0N3","UserId":null,"TraceId":"00-422a265cbe84a718c243499d9e4feedd-13bd4283a1be5bab-00","Application":"Appname"}

does anyone has an idea on where i could start looking for the problem?
How can i troubleshoot this?
The log is generated by the framework, we don't output this line in any part of the code.
Thankls in advance

Looks like you might be using CompactJsonFormatter, but need RenderedCompactJsonFormatter - posting your logging configuration code would clear this up.
